# How do I know when I can offer Live Text in my app on iOS 15?

Tags: ios

I want to offer Live Text (text recognition) in my app when it's available, but how can I tell when it's available? iOS 15 is required, and that's easy to determine, but Live Text also requires an A12 or later processor, which isn't readily detectable AFAIK.

How can I tell if an iDevice supports Live Text? And yes, I want to find out *before* trying to use it, so I can provide a different UI when it's available. Is there anything like ARKit's isSupported property I can query for Live Text?

Answer (score 0):

It appears the A12 requirement is only for Apple's apps (presumably to optimize performance), as I have text recognition happily working on lesser processors and the app using it is on sale in the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

from apple document:

> To determine whether the data scanner runs on the user’s device, pass captureTextFromCamera(*:) to the canPerformAction(*:withSender:) method.

On iOS 15

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *), UITextfield().canPerformAction(#selector(UIResponder.captureTextFromCamera(_:)), withSender: self) {
            print("support live text")
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(UIResponder.captureTextFromCamera(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
```

On iOS 16, you can do it like this:

```
import VisionKit

if #available(iOS 16.0, *),ImageAnalyzer.isSupported {
   // here is live text available
}
```